# Why are high energies equivalent to short distances?

Tags: particle-physics, scales

Why are the regimes in high-energy collisions called **short distances**?

Qualitatively I only know that the higher the given energy of the colliding particles "*the smaller are the pieces yielded by cracking the collision particles*". Is there a quantitative derivation of the term relating the energy $E$ and the distance $x$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Energy is related to frequency via Planck's relationship $E=h\nu$ and frequency is related to wavelength via the speed of light $\nu=c/\lambda$. Therefore, the higher the energy the smaller the associated wavelength. This wavelength represents the resolution with which one makes an observation.

Answer (score 1):

We use human-friendly units, *unnatural* units. In *natural* units $$\hbar = c = 1$$

This makes time units equal to space units ($T=L$) and it makes energy units equal to inverse space units $([E]=1/L)$.

So, in a very **fundamental** sense, large energies mean small distances because energy *is* inverse distance.

Other answers are correct, but they express the human story of understanding the laws of nature, not anything *really* fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

Because the [de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) is short for high energies.